# How to render shopify app content to shopify store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

I am using Shopify default theme Debut and i want to integrate the ajax filter for products filter like this ([AjaxFilter](https://boost-pfs-vertical.myshopify.com/collections/dresses?_bt=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaEpJaVZpYjI5emRDMXdabk10ZG1WeWRHbGpZV3d1YlhsemFHOXdhV1o1TG1OdmJRWTZCa1ZVIiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0xMi0wMVQxNjoyMDoxNy41MjRaIiwicHVyIjoicGVybWFuZW50X3Bhc3N3b3JkX2J5cGFzcyJ9fQ%3D%3D--24d251259f37202a236ed1191b6c2bd13f81c76f)) without using any paid app. I am creating own public app and its working fine. I also fetch the list of products of app and also created the script tag.

1. App Created successfully and render products
   [image]
2. Script tag created successfully and able to render the hard-code text on Shopify store.
   [image]

But now point is this i want to render the product listing from app to store theme.
I go through the all tutorial and document of Shopify did not found any suitable solution.

I also try the proxy but did not work.
[image]

Comment: If you are creating your own public, why don't you make it in a way that it returns a JSON list of products based on the parameters you pass to it? And then arrange the frontend using Javascript?

Comment: If you are wanting to render products, get yourself a storefront API token, and then use that pattern. Your use case is exactly what that is for.

Comment: Is there any standard Shopify documentation that i can follow to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Create Ajax script in shopify theme frontend using script js and call your app server product list method. in your app server use GraphQL Shopify api for fetch products list Or Shopify rest admin api.

Shopify GraphQl:https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/examples/product
Shopify Rest Admin Api:https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products

Comment: Is there any standard Shopify documentation that i can follow to achieve this?

Comment: https://community.shopify.com/c/Technical-Q-A/Post-request-for-product-and-script-tag/td-p/672553 for script tag

Comment: through the proxy https://github.com/devtees/shopify-product-filter

Comment: Thank you for your answers i found the solution i done its using shopify script tag.